# React JS how to show password in input field for 5 seconds and then hide it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an eye icon, that has `onClick` event that changes visibility of password. It is easy to make it visible or not, just by clicking the eye button. I use `useState` for that. But I want to show the password only for 3 seconds and then hide it. Here I am facing some troubles.

```js
const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

const handleHidePassword = () => {
    setShowPassword(false);
};

var time;

const handleShowPassword = () => {
    clearTimeout(time);
    setShowPassword(true);
    time = setTimeout(handleHidePassword, 3000);
};
```

Actually, this code works, but has a bug. If I click the eye icon several times in a row, the password disappears quicker that after 3000 ms. I understand that the problem is that `setTimeout` is not being refreshed after each click. I tried to fix that by adding `clearTimeout(time);` but this didn't help.

I am new to JavaScript, so I am looking forward to receiving some understandable pieces of advice.

Comment: Could you share your component code in stackbiltz or codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a debounce to prevent the user from spamming the button.
Alternatively, you can make it that clicking the button resets a "show timer" to 3000ms:

```js
const [showPasswordTime, setShowPasswordTime] = useState(0);
const showPassword = Date.now() < showPasswordTime;

// Little hack to trigger a re-render of your component
// (just need to set this with a value different from last render)
const [, forceUpdate] = useState();

console.log("Render", showPasswordTime - Date.now(), showPassword);

const handleHidePassword = () => {
    setShowPasswordTime(0);
};

const handleShowPassword = () => {
    // Make it that the password will be hidden for at least 3000ms
    setShowPasswordTime(Date.now() + 3000);
    // Make your component re-render after 3000ms
    // which will then check if `showPasswordTime` has passed or not.
    // (setTimeout will wait *at least* 3000ms)
    setTimeout(() => forceUpdate(Date.now()), 3000);
};
```

*[Playground with example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-uoji4?file=/index.js)*

This way, you're not "toggling" the visibility after 3000ms. You're saying that the password should be shown for (at least) the next 3000ms. And you use `setTimeout` with `forceUpdate` to tell React "re-render my component in 3000ms" to check for that. If the time changed in the meantime, it'll still keep the password shown.

The only "bad" thing with this approach is that if your user presses the button multiple times within 3000ms, your component will render a few  times too many, but that's fine. You should assume that your components can re-render at any time.